# Dropzone.js Calling querySelector() on file param

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

```
myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
    if(file.status === 'success') {
        console.log(file.querySelector('.file-status'));
    }
});
```

I am getting the file object (a reference to the Preview DOM) however, as stated in the [manual](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-complete).

But when I try to access it's members, I get `file.querySelector is not a function`

Do I need to convert the file object or access it's members in any other way?

Comment: Query selector is a standard DOM function- Try document.querySelector('.file-status')

Comment: Doing that always selects the .file-status for the first image only. I need to select the .file-status relative to the file object returned. Do I need to use jQuery selector to do this?

Comment: No-
JQuery will just act as synthetic sugar for querySelector  function.
The thing is that you are trying to run a DOM function on a file object.

Try doing this.querySelector('.file-status')

Comment: Still says "this.querySelector is not a function"

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out:

Had to call the previewElement member first.

file.previewElement.querySelector('.file-status')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had to use the `previewElement` member to call `querySelector()`.

```
myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
    if(file.status === 'success') {
        console.log(file.previewElement.querySelector('.file-status'));
    }
});
```